# Firebase / Google Analytics

Tags: react-native, google-analytics, expo, firebase-analytics

I am using firebase sdk with Expo.  In order to link users accross sessions and different devices we use the following `setUserId(user._id)`.

This occurs after a user logs in and authenticates.

On logout I call `setUserId(null)`.

My questions is: does setting the user id to null erase the previous user tracking data from GA.  Should I be setting to null at logout?  I can't find any concrete documentation on how setting to null impacts the data collection.

The goal is to track unique users across months, years etc.  Is the above configured correctly or is there some issue with setting to `null` on logout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove the User ID by setting it to null or replace it with a new user ID. userID is just a user property that goes with all events after it is set so you need to set it to null when user logs out and set a new user ID when a different user logs in.

From documentation:

The value of the user property. Values can be up to 36 characters long. **Setting the value to null removes the user property.**

https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/analytics/FirebaseAnalytics#setUserId(java.lang.String)